# Extracting JSON variable using bash

Tags: linux, json, bash, grep

I need to extract the variable from a JSON encoded file and assign it to a variable in Bash.

excerpt...from file.json

```
  "VariableA": "VariableA data", 
    "VariableB": [
        "VariableB1", 
        "VariableB2", 
        "VariableB3", 
        "VariableB3"
    ],
```

I've gotten somewhere with this

```
variableA=$(fgrep -m 1 "VariableA" file.json )
```

but it returns the whole line. I just want the data

For the VariableB I need to replace the list with comma separated values.

I've looked at awk, sed, grep, regexpressions and really given the learning curve...need to know which one to use, or a better solution.

Thanks for your suggestions...but this is perfect
git://github.com/kristopolous/TickTick.git

Answer (score 7):

You are better off using a JSON parser.  There are many listed at http://json.org/ including two for the BASH shell.

- http://kmkeen.com/jshon/
- https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh

Comment: jsawk worked for me. And it was fairly easy to install on OS X.

Answer (score 4):

There is powerful command-line JSON tool  [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Extracting single value is easy:

```
variableA=$(jq .VariableA file.json)
```

For comma separated array contents try this

```
variableB=$(jq '.VariableB | @csv' file.json)
```

or

```
variableB=$(jq '.VariableB | .[]' file.json | tr '\n' ',' | head -c-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using Perl they have a 'open()' function that will pipe a file with the json function 'to_json'. And if you want to extract json you can use the 'from_json' function.  You can check it out here:

http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.0/lib/open.pm

http://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#to_json

http://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#from_json ( you might also try using decode json as well)